# Bool function handling with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, linq, boolean

I am trying to do something with ajax success function on the basis of `true`, `false` bool result.

Its when I cross check email against database-

**Function-**

```
 public bool RegisterEmail(string email) {
            var registeredemail = (from u in db.FunRegistereds
                                   where u.EmailAddress == email
                                   select u).ToList();
            if (registeredemail.Count() == 0 && registeredemail == null) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

**Ajax handling-**

```
$(function () {
    $('#exist-email').on('keyup', function () {
        var email = $('#exist-email').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Account/RegisterEmail/?email=' + email,
            type: 'post',
            success: function (data) {
                if (!data) {
                    $('.avalibility-email').html("<h2>" + "'" + email + "'" + "</h2>" + " Is" + "<b>" + " not" + "</b>" + "</b>" + " available for email address.");
                } else {
                    $('.avalibility-email').html("<h2>" + "'" + email + "'" + "</h2>" + " Is" + "<b>" + " available " + "</b>" + "</b>" + "for email address.");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

But I don't get results on basis of `true` or `false`.

Comment: Inside the ajax `success` method, what you're getting in console if you put `console.log(data)` inside it?

Comment: @palaѕн, Yes I could see everything was coming fine from server's side.

Answer (score 0):

may be giving error on this line?

```
if (registeredemail.Count == 0 && registeredemail == null) {
```

would have to be like this:

```
if (registeredemail == null || registeredemail.Count == 0) {
```